# WCF: Passing a value type parameter to an operation that returns a message contract

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, value-type, messagecontract

**THE SITUATION:**

I have this service contract:

```
[ServiceContract(ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign)]
public interface IMyServiceContract
{
    //This WORKS! Because GUIDWRAPPER and Group have a MessageContract
    [OperationContract]
    Group GetA(GUIDWRAPPER id);

    //This DOES NOT WORK, because int has no MessageContract!
    [OperationContract]
    Group GetB(int id);
}
```

In this case Group has a message contract and this message contract inherits the security level from the service contract. Group looks like this:

```
[MessageContract]
public class Group: Entity, ICloneable
{
    public Group(){}

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public String Name {get;set;}
}
```

The type GUIDWRAPPER is a simple wrapper für a Guid, which also has a message contract:

```
[MessageContract]
public class GUIDWRAPPER
{
    public GUIDWRAPPER() { }

    public GUIDWRAPPER(Guid id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

When I startup my service host, it complains that the operation **"GetB" is invalid**, because the return type "Group" has a message contract and the value type "int" has not. That's a possible security flaw.

"GetA" makes no problems because both, return type and parameter type, have message contracts.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS:**

1.) I could wrap all value types, like I did with the GUIDWRAPPER class, and give them a message contract. But that feels dirty and smelly to me.

2.) Delete all message contracts and just go with data contracts. Then I lose control, which data is sent and received.

**MY QUESTION:**

Is it possible to pass a simple value type (like int in this case) to a service operation, which has a message contract return type? (like GetB in this case)

Are there any attributes for the operation contract to allow that?

Comment: Hmm why the `[DataMember]` in addition to a `[MessageBodyMember`?

Comment: Please ignore the [DataMember] for the moment, because it is all about the Message Contract issue. Thank you.

Comment: @MickyD Yes, I already know that, as you can see from my example code. The class GUID is a wrapper for a Guid and has a message contract. As I wrote in question, it works. My only and simple question is, if it is possible to pass a simple value type and NOT any message contract. I had read this article before I wrote the question, but I could not find the answer.

Comment: Oh I didn't see `GUID` my bad.  Maybe call it `GuidWrapper` or better yet suffix it with _request_ as in `GetARequest` which is convention.

Comment: Are you set on using `MessageContract`?  If not fall back to `DataContract`.  Otherwise you need to be due-diligent

Comment: No. There are classes where DataContract would be ok and others where I need full control of the message. This is where I use MessageContract. I know the difference between DataContract and MessageContract. And I know, that 95 % of all real world situations are ok with DataContract.

Comment: Beyond my above question, I feel curious, why the parameter has to be a MessageContract. The thing is, the incoming and outgoing MessageContract can be completely different, but it has to be MessageContract. It makes no sense to me. So I was hoping, if someone knows a workaround for this. Maybe an attribute for the OperationContract or something else.....